# differences between double colon and global variables use?

Tags: tcl

Very recently I found out about the `namespace` concept and the use of double-colon (::) for program variables.

Before I start reshaping all my scripts, I wanted to know if there is a real difference between accessing a variable with the `global` keyword and with the double colon syntax.
e.g.
    `set var bla`
    `proc kuku {} { puts $::var }`

vs.
`proc gaga {} {global var ; puts $var}`

In both cases I'm getting 'bla' written to my screen.

What am I missing?
I understand that editing the variable will be a bit problematic (is it even possible?), but for read-only vars, is there a difference between the two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're talking about the same variable. With the `::var` form, you're using the fully-qualified name, whereas with the form with `global` you're making a local link to the global variable (which *really* is a pointer to the global variable). Reading from or writing to them should work exactly the same, whichever way you choose.

There is a measurable difference between the two. With `global`, you've got the extra cost of setting up the link, but thereafter for the remainder of the procedure the cost per use (read or write) is quite a lot lower. With the other form, you're not paying any setup overhead, but the per-use cost is higher. For one use only, the cost of the two are pretty similar. If you're using the variable several times, `global` is cheaper. OTOH, sometimes it is clearer to use the fully qualified version anyway (particularly true with `vwait` and `trace`) despite the reduction in speed.

I find that I access the `::env` and `::tcl_platform` arrays using their fully-qualified form, but most other things will get accessed via `global`. That's just my preference though.

---

Here's an example interactive session:

```
% set x 1
1
% proc y1 {} {incr ::x;return ok}
% time { y1 } 10000
0.5398216 microseconds per iteration
% proc y2 {} {global x;incr x;return ok}
% time { y2 } 10000
0.4537753 microseconds per iteration
% proc z1 {} {return $::x}
% time { z1 } 10000
0.4864713 microseconds per iteration
% proc z2 {} {global x; return $x}
% time { z2 } 10000
0.4433554 microseconds per iteration
```

(I wouldn't expect you to get the same absolute figures as me. Do your own performance testing. I would expect similar *relative* figures…)

Comment: I'm using vnc, so measuring the actual work time of each form is very inaccurate...